# Django on IIS large file upload

Tags: django, iis, file-upload, server

I am trying to host a simple Django web application on a windows 10 machine with IIS 10 with FastCGI.
As I my program is working with huge files, I would like to be able to upload large file (up to 10Gb).
In my Django code, I already upload the files as chunks using this code:

```
tmpFile = NamedTemporaryFile('w', delete=False)

        try:
            with tmpFile:
                for chunk in inputFasta.chunks():
                    tmpFile.write(chunk.decode("utf-8"))

            open(tmpFile.name, 'r')
            fastaSequences = SeqIO.parse(tmpFile.name, 'fasta')

        finally:
            os.unlink(tmpFile.name)
```

but it is still not running.

On my IIS, I adjusted the **maxAllowedContentLength** and **maxRequestEntityAllowed**  to their respective maximum (maxAllowedContentLength: 2147483648, maxRequestEntityAllowed: 4294967295).
Is there any other adjustment I can do? Or do I need another programm to help me doing it?
My program works fine with smaller sized files.

Comment: It is impossible to upload a 10Gb file. The size of the file you upload cannot exceed the value set in maxAllowedContentLength.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot!
But is it not possible to upload it in chunks?

Comment: Sorry, I’m too absolute. You can’t upload 10Gb files directly, but chunking is possible.

Comment: Ok, thanks! 
Is it done using JS? Because I used Django for it and it did not work.

Comment: If you want to use js, you can refer to this link: [Split an uploaded file into multiple chunks using javascript](https://newbedev.com/split-an-uploaded-file-into-multiple-chunks-using-javascript).

Comment: Thanks a lot!
But how to deal with the URL? Is there a certain link for the simple Django application?

Comment: Oh and do I need to catch the upcoming stream in Django? So request.FILES[] would not work?

Comment: What does deal with the URL mean? you only need to deploy your project to iis. this link is for [Django](https://pypi.org/project/django-chunked-upload/).